# Cannot install nginx (dependency issue) on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: apt, nginx, raspberrypi

I have an installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on a Raspberry Pi 3 with rbenv installed properly already. I'm trying to install nginx/passenger (integrated version) on it, but the following is happening.

```
user@pi:~$ sudo apt-get install nginx
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-extras (>= 1:1.10.2-8.5.1.2~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: nginx-extras (< 1:1.10.2-8.5.1.2~xenial1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
```

When I try to install `nginx-extras` manually it tells me the same about `nginx-common`. I've installed nginx/passenger on several Ubuntu systems but haven't run into this before - might be Pi related? I've seen lots of links of people having this issue from 9 months ago but I'm not sure why it's still occurring.

I did a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` today just in case. Still nothing.

None of the answers I've found work for me.

I initially added the steps for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967496/7397261) (which is on the original how-to I followed, except using a passenger source entry for Xenial). I get the above error when I do that.

I then tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28912479/7397261) but it installs a standalone nginx version which works, but doesn't have Passenger integration.

edit: Definitely on xenial: `cat /etc/os-release` gives me

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

I don't consider this a duplicate since this is an issue that seems to be specific to the Raspberry Pi 3 hardware. I have installed nginx/passenger many times on non-Pi machines, virtual machines, linode instances, etc etc and never had any issues like this. I may be wrong of course!

Comment: Check out the top voted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818597/nginx-and-passenger-dependencies-issue-digital-ocean-deployment). Seems like your situation

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to install a version of nginx that doesn't mesh with Passenger. (I thought it had solved the issue, but not) Still looking into it.

Comment: After a lot of digging I'm pretty convinced this is due to outdated package information for the Raspberry Pi port of Ubuntu I have.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy nginx nginx-extras`?

Comment: Is it a duplicate question if it is specific to hardware which isn't used by most users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After no luck with other answers, I determined it was probably the ubuntu package combinations available to the raspberry pi version I have. I may be wrong on this, of course :-)

I ended up installing from source using the gem installer found at the [Passenger tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/rubygems_norvm/).